# Xaml Animation error unclear

Tags: xaml, animation

I have a UWP application and sometimes when I navigate to another Page I get the following exception when debugging

```
WARNING: Animation of "113" on "I" is not independent and will be skipped
```

How can I found out what "113" or "I" means?

Comment: I would assume it has something to do with a transition animation but would likely need more info to diagnose. Try removing any transition/themetransition animations from where it occurs to identify the culprit.